# Record audio from Bluetooth headset

Tags: microphone, bluetooth-audio, headset, audio-recording

When I try to record audio and have my Bluetooth headset connected, the phone instead records from the internal phone microphone. The headsets all have included microphones for handsfree calling.

This is reproducible with all top-rated audio recorders and three bluetooth headsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an app that supports recording with a Bluetooth headset like: cinema fv-5 lite

Comment: Finally!  Something that actually DOES use the bluetooth mic.  (+1 for that)  A lot of apps say they do, and even have a setting for it with the correct name for my headset, but like the OP said, they still use the internal mic regardless.  I only want to record audio though, and I didn't see a way in Cinema to disable the video recording.  Is that possible?